# Isolating unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Generally speaking good OO practices are enough to keep unit tests separate.  However, when things go really bad by causing a program crash, corrupting memory space, etc things can spill over to adjoining tests and give misleading results or simply be annoying in that it brings down the testing framework.  Does anyone know of any existing unit test frameworks that have a high level of isolation to protect against this sort of thing?  As an example, a simple approach would be to execute one fixture at a time on the command line but I'd be afraid it would be difficult to aggregate the results nicely.  The C++ project that I wanted this for currently is in cppunit but I'm not dead set on that framework if something like the Google Test Framework or CTest have this sort of support.  I briefly look at those two and I don't think i saw anything with that sort of strict isolation.  I'm mostly interested in Linux but cross-platform would be ideal.

In any case I played around with a small Linux (and probably others) proof of concept using cppunit if someone is interested.  Find the files at 
https://github.com/JohnDMcMaster/uvudec/tree/master/uvudec/testing/framework
You'll want helper_macros.*, serialized_test_result.*, and test_caller.*

Comment: Why is it difficult to aggregate the results?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. If a unit-test crashes your test program, the subsequent tests won't run. When you fix the test (or the system under test), then the subsequent tests run. Can you give an example of the kind of leakage you are trying to guard against?

Answer (score 0):

There are no frameworks like this. You would need to make seperate test suites for every test and so that they are seperate files. This would allow them to be run in complete isolation.

Instead of this you could use [boost.test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) as it has detection for memory leaks on Windows, which is a step in the right direction in my opinion.

Comment: You should add that Boost.Test can only detect memory leaks under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The natural isolation unit for this kind of thing is the process, and I'd say it is also the natural granularity level for this kind of problem:

If all your unit tests are compiled into one executable, chances are that they are so fast that you don't care whether a crashing one forces you to repeat the (set of) suite(s).

On the other hand, if all your unit tests are so many and take so long to run that a crashing one interrupting a test run is a major annoyance, then you prolly should be splitting them up into several exes anyway to make your unit tests more ganular. (Link times, devs being easily able to only run a subset, ...)